# Refer to a column by its number (index)

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, postgresql-9.2

I want to perform a select using an index (number) of a column. I tried:

```
select 1 from "user"
select '1' from "user"
```

but they don't do what I expect.

Comment: Of course they don’t, because they select the _values_ `1` and `'1'`, respectively.

Comment: While it may not be literally true, you have to assume that the table columns have no fixed order, so such a request would be poorly defined. If you need this, it seems likely that your structure needs to be rethought.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You cannot do this in postgres. Selecting a literal (such as `1` or `'1'`) would just return its value. The only place such indices are allowed is in the `order by` clause, and even there, they don't relate to the order of columns in the table, but in the select list:

```
SELECT   col1, col2, col3
FROM     my_table
ORDER BY 1
```

EDIT:
One caveat is using `order by <some index>` in conjunction with `select *`, which may seem as though the index related to the order of columns in the table. However, the `*` is first expanded to contain all columns, and only then is the `order by` clause applied. So ultimately, it does refer to the `select` list and not to the actual structure of the table.

EDIT2:
As @klin mentioned, postgres' `group by` clause also allows indices:

```
SELECT   col1, COUNT(*)
FROM     my_table
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: what if a column has no title, how do I do select then?

Comment: @Alex can you give a concrete example of such a situation?

Comment: It's useful in any `ORDER BY`, and can actually be a really big benefit if sorting by a complex and verbose expression.

Comment: Indeces may be also used in `GROUP BY` clauses.

Comment: It is a good response, elucidative, but it is not correct. It is possible using an alias. Like @BernardoJerez said in the other answer.

Comment: Submitted a revision to this answer to make it correct as originally noted by @felipe-mendes.

Answer (score 18):

When i need the FIRST column (and i don't know the column name) , i do something like this:

```
SELECT uno FROM _your_table_ as t(uno);
```

Just use an alias for table and columns!..

if you REALLY NEED the NUMBER 1 you could write something like this:

```
SELECT "1" FROM _your_table_ as t("1");
```

double quotes... ugly, but works!!!!

Comment: How does this actually work? What is this type of functionality in postgres called?

Comment: It's only an alias... https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-select.html

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways, to do this in PostgreSQL. The easiest one (I think) is creating a "function". Dig into the PG manual for working examples to start with. It's quite easy. You can choose from various languages. The lines here are for pl/pgsql but you'll get the idea:

First you retrieve the column name from the system catalog, doing something like this:

```
attname := select distinct attname from pg_attribute,pg_class where attrelid = pg_class.oid and attnum = 1 and pg_class.relname='user';
```

Then you concatenate this into a SQL statement:

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT ' || attname || ' FROM ...
```